# Facebook sharer not working in mobile devices

Tags: facebook, share

I have setup a link to share on facebook, this way:

```
var points=0;
points = update_points(points)
document.getElementById("share-link").innerHTML='<a id="facebook-share"  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?&p[url]=http://www.example.com/index.php?score='+points+'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

I used javacript to build the link because the url to share depend on score obtained.

So this is working perfectly on desktop browsers (Safari, Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc..). The problem is only with mobile devices. The link doesn't work at all. Actually the link sent to sharer through mobile devices is something like "http://":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by changing the url like that:

```
document.getElementById("share-link").innerHTML='<a id="facebook-share" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.example.com/index.php?score='+points+'" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

So the problem seems to be the "&p[url]" in url (that is working well on all desktop browsers):

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?&p[url]=
```

You may then prefer this approach which seems less buggy:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=
```